# "New Tab" as Tab in TabPane JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tabs

I have found various solutions on how to add Buttons inside a Tab or overlay on the TabPane, which however did not satisfy me.

What I want is to have a button beside the most right tab, like e.g. my browser offers it:
[image: The button right beside the '"New Tab" as Tab in']

What I have tried now is instead of adding a Button using the `setGraph(Node)` on this Tab, I have added a Tab that is treated different if selected.

```
    addTab = new Tab("+");
    addTab.setClosable(false);
    TabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> ov, Tab oldValue, Tab newValue) {
            if (newValue == addTab) {
                groupTabPane.getSelectionModel().select(oldValue);
                DO_ADD_TAB();
            }
        }
    });
```

To keep it the right most Tab I have a listener on the Tablist and always remove / add it again if the list is modified (maybe this can be done more elegantly)

However the problem I face is that the TabPane always needs a selection, if a Tab is present. Therefore on startup `DO_ADD_TAB()` is always executed. I can work around that using a boolean variable, but then the Tab is selected, and can not be selected again to add a new Tab. `TabPane.getSelectionModel().clearSelection()` does not work.

Can somebody advise how to add such a button more elegantly or how to make the TabPane accept no Selection if only this one Tab is present?

Comment: Why not just set a button (or even just a label) as the tab's graphic, and use an event handler on the button? Then you don't have to rely on selection at all.

Comment: Tried that, but the button did not cover the entire Tab, so the Tab was still selectable.

Comment: Rather than adding/removing the tab, can you just make it invisible and hence its contents unclickable.  Make it visible again when the user selects it.

Comment: @rossum I am afraid i do not really understand what you mean? Do you mean disable and enable on MouseOver?